# Multiple Security handler with Jetty ServletContextHandler

Tags: java, security, webserver, jetty

In Jetty's ServletContextHandler there is only 1 security handler which can be set. Is there a way to set multiple security handlers ? 
I was thinking if I can create a WrapperSecurityHandler and compose 2 security handlers inside it. Then based on request type use the specific security handler inside WrapperSecurityHandler::handle method to do the authentication. Then I can just set this WrapperSecurityHandler as security handler of ServletContextHandler. But am facing issues in this approach so was wondering if there is any other way or it's a limitation in Jetty.